# has-error not removed for fields having ng-touched class when removing validator using clearValidators()?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-formly, ngx-formly

Dependencies used

```
"@angular/cli": "^11.2.10",
"@ngx-formly/bootstrap": "^5.10.22",
"@ngx-formly/core": "^5.10.22"
```

There is an issue with the formly form validation classes when we remove the validator from the already touched field.
[Form-field-image](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/21072718/158772314-2e44122f-70a4-4d84-926c-7f51ad6a9ea6.png)
[image]
I have a formly form with three fields. In the Initial stage, every field is a mandatory field. Password and Public Key fields are related to each other. If there is a value in the Password then the Public Key field needs to be disabled and no need for validators for Public Key and vice versa.

If I touched the Password field and do not add any value in the field will show a validator error. Then adding value in the Public key field will disable the Password Field and * symbol and the Validation message gets removed. But the red-color border remains the same and the form is also invalid in these cases.

I noticed that the is-invalid class name was not removed from the disabled field. Also, there is a has-error class in the parent div of the input field. You can see the class names in the image
[image: div_with_has-error]

I also used expression properties, the same issue also there.

```
expressionProperties: {
'templateOptions.disabled': () => {
return this.model.sftpPassword != undefined && this.model.sftpPassword != ""
},
'templateOptions.required': (model: any, formState: any) => {
return formState.mainModel.sftpPassword == undefined || formState.mainModel.sftpPassword == "";
},
},
```

Comment: Did you use `updateValueAndValidity()` after `clearValidators()`?

Comment: @MishaMashina I also tried the updateValueAndValidity() after clearValidators().
The has-error class name not removed from the input.